# Convergence in distribution sequence of r.v.'s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If I have a sequence of random variables $Y_n$ which converges in distribution
to the exponential distribution with mean 1

How to conclude that 
$n Y_n$ does NOT converge to any random variable in distribution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y_n \rightarrow Y$ in distribution means that
$$ \Pr \left[ Y_n \leqslant y \right] \rightarrow \Pr \left[ Y \leqslant y
   \right] = 1 - \exp \left( - y \right) $$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, applying the above to $nY_n$, you see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ Y_n \leqslant \frac{y}{n} \right] & \rightarrow & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
as $n \rightarrow \infty$ which is not a distribution (it is the constant
function 0).
And, to make things more explicit, the exact way to compute $\Pr \left[ Y_n
\leqslant \frac{y}{n} \right]$ is through the empirical distribution function
$$F_n \left( y \right) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n 1 \left( Y_n \leqslant
\frac{y}{n} \right)$$ where $1 \left( . \right)$ is the indicator variable.

Comment: not convinced.. thanks though

Comment: @Yobo It is more constructive to say why you are not convinced.

Comment: i dont think you showed anything in terms of convergence in distribution please check the definition of weak convergence exactly...

Comment: @Yobo The proof is upon you! I have written sufficient details in my answer to show how I was using weak convergence. Again, it is more constructive if you point exactly the place where I am "mis-using" the concept of convergence in distribution.

Comment: May be we should put this way: If there is convergence in distribution then the limit r.v. cumulative distribution function F is the limit of F_n where F is continuous. What you show above is that all points for F_n give zero. So that gives one possibility the resulting distribution function is nowhere continouos but this can not be the case since an increasing function is almost everywhere continuous. Hence there is no resulting r.v Y... I guess that might be an answer...

Comment: @Yobo No, what I showed is that you could not have convergence in distribution because the sequence of empirical distribution functions converge pointwise to the constant zero function. You are applying the definition of convergence of distribution before proving that convergence actually occurs to "require" that the limit is a distribution function. Do you see how this reasoning is circular!

Comment: how about this one: If there is convergence in distribution then the limiting r.v. Y's cumulative distribution function F is the limit of F_n where F is continuous. What you show above is that for all points y in real line for F_n give zero. So that gives one possibility the resulting distribution function being increasing hence continuous a.e. is zero a.e. Hence there is a sequence as y goes to infinity giving F(y) = 0 but since F(y) is a distribution function at the same time limit F(y) is 1.Hence this is a contradiction. There is no r.v. Y with CDF F.

Comment: @Yobo Again, the limit is NOT a distribution function.